# how to find specific data in many columns?

Tags: python, pandas

a DataFrame name is df_y
I want to find some data('K','m') on many columns
so i made this code

```
df_y[df_y[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].str.contains('K|M')]
```

then I could see a error "'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'str'"

i think the code has problem by containg many columns...

IDK how to make that correctly..!

Comment: Provide some sample input/output data. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/20109391/17769815

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `df.apply`

```
df_y[df_y[['column1', 'column2', 'column3']].apply(lambda x:x.str.contains('K|M'))]
```

Comment: Just in case, if you want to perform the filter throughout the dataframe, it will work too.

Answer (score 0):

for indexing and selecting data use '&' and '|' operators. https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html

```
df_y[df_y['column1'].str.contains('K|M') & df_y['column2'].str.contains('K|M') & df_y['column3'].str.contains('K|M')]
```

Comment: is there no way to write the code at once?? if they have columns number [-1:-3]..?

Comment: Unfortunately no. This is the only way to do it, to avoid any ambiguity. Try df_y['column1'].str.contains('K|M'): this will give you a pd.Series of boolean values. Pandas doesn't know if you're looking for the 'K|M' pattern in 'column1' AND 'column2' AND 'column3', or in 'column1' OR 'column2' OR 'column3', or even a mix like ('column1' AND 'column2') OR 'column3'. Therefore you are constrained to use the pandas '&' and '|' logical operators to be explicit on your index selection.

Answer (score 0):

You have an inconveniently large number of columns
and want to find where a rare string appears
in any of those columns. Ok. A pair of text processing
solutions come to mind.

## 1. CSV file

Serialize out to the filesystem with [df.to_csv('y.csv')](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html)
and then

```
$ egrep -n --color 'K\|M' y.csv
```

## 2. str()

Perhaps you prefer to use that approach
while remaining entirely within python.

There are good reasons for people criticizing the
slow speed of non-vectorized operations like `.iterrows()`.
But if you want a quick'n'dirty solution,
this should suffice:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    row = str(df.iloc[i])
    if 'K|M' in row:
        print(i)
        print(df.iloc[i])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following code:

```
temp = df.copy()
num_of_columns = 2
temp.iloc[:, 1:3] = temp.iloc[:, 1:3].apply(lambda x: x.str.contains('K|M'))
index = temp[temp.iloc[:, 1:3].eq([True] * num_of_columns).all(1)].index.to_numpy()
df.iloc[index]
```

- Replace num_of_columns with number of columns you want to perform the operation on
- replace 1:3 inside the temp.iloc with the columns you want to work on